# Get current max value of column and input into new column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to get the current max value of a column in pandas. For example, I want to take the column `[ask]` and create a new column `[high_of_day]` to show what the maximum value of the ask column has been *up to the this point*, and to keep repeating that max value in the `[high_of_day]` column until a new value in the ask column that is greater appears.

Data Input

```
data = [['9:00',1,0],['10:00',2,0],['11:00',3,0],['12:00',4,0],['13:00',2,0],['14:00',5,0]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['DateTime','Ask','High_of_Day'],dtype=float)
```

Output

```
  DateTime  Ask  High_of_Day
0     9:00  1.0          0.0
1    10:00  2.0          0.0
2    11:00  3.0          0.0
3    12:00  4.0          0.0
4    13:00  2.0          0.0
5    14:00  5.0          0.0
```

I have tried using a wide range of loops but can't seem to get it right.

The desired outcome I am trying to get is:

```
  DateTime  Ask  High_of_Day
0     9:00  1.0          1.0
1    10:00  2.0          2.0
2    11:00  3.0          3.0
3    12:00  4.0          4.0
4    13:00  2.0          4.0
5    14:00  5.0          5.0
```

Any help on getting the right algorithm would be extremely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`pd.Series.cummax`*

```
s = df3.Ask.cummax()
print(s)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
Name: Ask, dtype: float64

df3['High_of_Day'] = s
print(df3)
  DateTime  Ask  High_of_Day
0     9:00  1.0          1.0
1    10:00  2.0          2.0
2    11:00  3.0          3.0
3    12:00  4.0          4.0
4    13:00  2.0          4.0
5    14:00  5.0          5.0
```

---

**Option 2**
*`np.maximum.accumulate`*

```
df3['High_of_Day'] = np.maximum.accumulate(df3.Ask)
print(df3)
  DateTime  Ask  High_of_Day
0     9:00  1.0          1.0
1    10:00  2.0          2.0
2    11:00  3.0          3.0
3    12:00  4.0          4.0
4    13:00  2.0          4.0
5    14:00  5.0          5.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great, I appreciate the help